# Where can I find a list of LocalizableInteger values?

Tags: localization, wix

My `Product` element has a `Language` field that's set to `1033` (for `en-us`). How do I find out what the values are for other languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's the mapping table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912047%28WinEmbedded.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Excellent, just what I wanted.